# Best approach to de-serialise encrypted query param in java?

Tags: java, httprequest, deserialization

I have to make a http request with encrypted query param from one end to another. Say for an example,

```
String queryParam = "bookName=WingsOfFire&author=AbdulKalam";
String encryptedQueryParam = encrypt(queryParam, encryptionKey);
```

The final url would be like

`domain_name`?`encryptedQueryParam`

On the other end, I would decrypt the query params and obtain the query String. Like

```
String decryptParam = decrypt(encryptedQueryParam, decryptKey);
```

Here I'm manually de-serialising my query params at the other end instead of `request.getPameter("value")`.

Is there any other option to handle it in a better way? Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: If you need to encrypt information inside a HTTP request, you shouldn't use GET request but you should use POST request : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Do not forget to encode ( e.g. base64uri) , proper encryption should include some salt and unique IV (for some encr. methods)

Comment: @MickaëlB It's actually a "POST" request - but I'm sending the query params in my request as encrypted

Comment: @GabrielVince : Yeah you are right ! The proper encryption should include some salt and unique IV - I'm doing that :)

Comment: If you're using a POST request, what do you mean "The final url would be like `domain_name?encryptedQueryParam`" ?

Comment: I'm not sending the query params in body - whereas I'm sending it as query param in the header